# Google Assitant Conversation Action

Tags: android

I want to create a conversation action on action console and on a particular point after i set input on google assitant i want to redirect user with input capture inside my android app .

I created project on action console then added intent over there now i want to capture user answer about my query and then submit that answer inside my app

For example

User will ask assitant

StartBreastfeed

then assitant will reply
Which Side ?
then user reply
left
then assitant ask baby name
user reply with name
after user enter name i want user to redirect to my android app with input user provided
Anybody please guide how i can acheive this . I created Conversation action on action console on my app side what changes i need to make

Comment: @anybody assist here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am creating project on action console and i want to show response based on webhook calls.Like i want to interact with my server before showing response to user .How this can be done